# Determine machine epsilon

Tags: numerical-analysis

Consider a base 2 computer that stores floating point numbers using a 6 bit normalized mantissa (x.xxxxx), a 4 digit exponent and a sign for each.

a) For this machine, what is machine epsilon?

b) What is the smallest positive number that can be represented exactly in this machine?

c) What mantissa and exponent are stored for the value 1/10?

I shall present my answers.  My question is to know if my answers are correct or incorrect.

My answer for a): 1 would be represented by $1.00000\times 2^0$.  The next smallest number after 1 would be $1.00001\times 2^0$.  Hence machine epsilon is $1.00001-1.00000=0.00001$.  This is equivalent to $\frac{1}{32}$ in base 10.

My answer for b): The smallest positive number that can be represented exactly in this machine would be $1.00000\times 2^{-1111}$

My answer for c): $\frac{1}{10}$ is the repeating decimal $0.\overline{00011}$ in base 2.  So the mantissa should be 0.00011 BUT I DON'T KNOW what the exponent should be.

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 1):

a) Correct!

b) This seems to be correct, but I have to say, this representation for exponents is very strange. A four digit exponent plus a sign bit lets you represent an exponent between $-1111_2$ to $1111_2$, however, it has two representations for an exponent of zero, and gives no way to represent the number zero.

c) No. Remember, the leading $1$ is implicit in a normalised number. Hint: $0.\overline{00011}_2$ = $1.\overline{10001}_2 \times 2^{-4}$

Comment: Please consider not to encourage undesired posting behaviour (cf D.W.'s comment on the question).